# dynamic update .dll file from url in c# if any changes happens ?

Tags: c#, dll, wsdl

I have created a .dll file from a wsdl url and deploy it on my server 
After some days there are some more  changes in wsdl file but i don't want to create again a new .dll file and delete old once and redeploy

suggest me if it is possible to update .dll file dynamically if changes happens any time

Comment: What if there are breaking changes? How do you expect this update to happen dynamically?

Comment: some parameters may be added or updated and i will handle breaking changes in my code

Comment: some times there are multiple url for same wsdl file and  they process  according to url